# ImageMagick unable to turn white in transparent without getting ugly edges

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to remove the white from 5k+ pictures and turn it into transparent. Unfortunately, when I do this it leaves a ugly edge around the black parts in various gray tones.

I tried various methods including -trim and -fuzz but I am unable to get it working properly. All it should do is remove the white and leave everything else intract.

I have to crank the fuzz so high for the arrows to remotely look a little bit properly, that ImageMagick will remove other stuff that it shouldn't as well.

Can someone help me out please?

The original image:
[image]

The image after using ImageMagick (added green so you can see the ugly edge better):
[image]

The image after using ImageMagick (original)

[image]

So basically what I want is to remove all white from the pictures and make those transparent. Anything else should NOT be affected.

The image was made in 8k resolution in Illustrator which I then exported to a single PNG image (transparent). Then I used Bramus' tile cutter script for Photoshop to cut my image into tiles (which forces a white background unfortunately).

So finally I wanted to try ImageMagick to remove the white but as you can read, I am unable to so far.

Hope someone can help me out.

The code I currently used:

```
for /R "C:\Users\<Username>\Desktop\map" %I in (*.png) do magick "%I" -fuzz 69% -transparent #FFFFFF "%I"
```

What it should look like in the end when I put it on top of my other layer(s):

[image]

I tried increasing the blur 0x2 for example, on big pictures that works better, but the smaller pictures lose to much detail and the lines are barely visible. It is either big pictures are oké or low pictures are oké but never both so far whatever I try.

A sample of a smaller image with the blur set to 0x2. You can see some white was left there too.

[image]

If it helps, I can zip a couple of small, regular and big images for testing purposes?

Original files: https://easyupload.io/8yep41
After using ImageMagick: https://easyupload.io/6xlm2f

Single image comparison: https://easyupload.io/gi5dvm

The command I used is:

```
for /R "C:\Users\<Username>\Desktop\map\<FolderName>" %I in (*.png) do magick "%I" -fuzz 10% -transparent white ( +clone -alpha extract -blur 0x1.2 -level 50x100% ) -alpha off -compose copyAlpha -composite "%I"
```

So I either have almost disappearing arrows on the low zoom ones (4 for example) but not on 6 or I have white borders. I also have white spots left at the arrow heads in multiple occasions.

Comment: For you "sample" download, where is your concern and what was the exact command you used to process the arrow image to make transparent and then to put it on the green background?

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick 7 on Windows, you can do

```
magick arrow.png -fuzz 10% -transparent white ^
( +clone -alpha extract -blur 0x1 -level 50x100% ) ^
-alpha off -compose copyAlpha -composite ^
new_arrow.png
```

[image]

If in a .bat script, I believe that you would need to double the % to %%.

**ADDITION**

Try this:

```
magick 17_original.png -fuzz 10% -transparent white ^
( +clone -alpha extract -blur 0x1.2 -level 85x100% ) ^
-alpha off -compose copyAlpha -composite ^
-background "rgb(6,120,0)" -alpha background -alpha off ^
17_original_green_fred.png
```

[image]

Comment: Dang, that is very nice! near perfect! when I add it on top of something else, there is a bit of a white/grey edge around the arrow... is there a way to solve that?

Comment: Try increasing the -blur to 0x1.5 or 0x2.

Comment: Working perfectly, just one downside... it is changing the color somehow. When I create the tiles with Bramus' tile cutter, I add a background color of #0e0e0e. After running your command the color changes to #131313 for some reason. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I do not understand. Can you post an example and also your command line for adding the background. Why output format are you creating? If JPG, it will have limited colors. Similarly if PNG8, it will have limited colors and those can change depending upon the overlay image and its colors. Fixing the problem will depend upon what you are doing and what format.

Comment: I am using PNG files. The command I am using is the command you gave me. I will edit my post to include a before and after example. Give me a couple of minutes please.

Comment: I am sorry, it was my own fault (had to do with my FTP). It is working ;) Anyways... on the smaller images there is a ugly white line around the black now. When I look at the bigger images this line is nearly non-existant. Is there any way to fix this? My images are map tiles used for zoom levels 4 - 7 in LeafletJs. As said, large images (zoomed in) are near perfect but the small images (not zoomed in) have these borders. I will update my first post ;)

Comment: Post the tile image before the overlay and the overlay image so that I can test with it. What was your command to do the overlay?

Comment: I will do that right away, I will edit my main message.

Comment: Please zip as you offered so that we can experiment with your actual files

Comment: Are you trying to edit my answer. Your additional information should be put in your question, not my answer.

Comment: Something went wrong sorry. I added a download link to my main post! those are the original files. Most important are the files in the folders 3, 4, 5 and 6. I am using Leaflet so its build up us {zoom}/{x-ax}/{y-ax}.png.

Comment: You tried to add it to my answer, not your question. Please add it again to your question.

Comment: What is your code for overlaying on the green background or is it some different image that is green colored?

Comment: It indeed is a different image. The code is leaflet code like <l-tile-layer :url="">. But if you run ImageMagick and then open the file in photoshop and add a layer behind it with a green color or whatever color, you will see that some pictures have white-ish borders or spots on them as I described in my previous comments. So it has nothing to do with the code, it really is the image itself, or at least thats what I think.

Comment: You are not overlaying on green using Imagemagick? Why Photoshop and not Imagemagick?

Comment: Too many image in the download.  I just want one original tile and your overlay image and the command to combine them that shows the issue.  I opened a number of your folders and files and did not see anything bad. I do not know where to look. I need a simple reproducible example and code!

Comment: doing it with photoshop was just an example on how you can see it. Oké give me 1 sec ill make a new download with just 1 or 2 examples.

Comment: I added a Single image comparison link in my main post.

Comment: @Mithradantor See my ADDITION in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244699/discussion-between-fmw42-and-mithradantor).